# eclipse RCP juno 64 bit crashes on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, crash, terminal

I'm trying to install eclipse RCP 64 bit version on my Mac (10.7.5).

[image]

Whenever I tried to launch eclipse, I got this crash screen.

[image]

When I tried to start eclipse using command line, I got `Segmentation fault: 11` error message.

What might be wrong? RCP 32bit works fine, and eclipse classic 64bit version works also fine.

And it is just OK to use RCP 32bit version on Lion?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was from extracting downloaded tar file. I used pathfinder for untar it, but something might be wrong. I used `tar xvf` and now everything works fine.